# Checking if property is settable/deletable

Tags: python, properties

How do I check if a property is settable or deletable in Python?

The best I've found so far is

```
type(obj).__dict__["prop_name"].fset is not None
```

Comment: A good question! And your solution looks like the best solution there is.

Comment: I'd prefer saying `obj.__class__.prop_name.fset` to your idiom of `type(obj).__dict__["prop_name"].fset`, but I think that both are valid, and I agree with BasicWolf that your answer is probably best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good case when you should subscribe to "It's Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission" philosophy, and just handle the exception in case property is *not* settable/deletable.

```
try:
    x.prop = 42
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Comment: Good answer.  I considered this, but I am automatically building UI from properties and using their “settability” to decide set the `ItemIsEditable` flag.  I guess I could check with `x.prop = x.prop` or change my design.

Comment: @Neil: If you wrote the code in question and know that saying `x.prop = x.prop` will always be safe, then that check would be fine.  However, property setters may do unexpected things like hit the database or increment a counter or otherwise change the internal state of your system, so I would avoid calling them unless there's no other approach.  The solution you mention in your question seems best to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to know up front without trying. You can't know for certain if an object has a strange `__setattr__` or similar that will break the abstraction you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

The following program tests three functions designed to find out if a class or instance property supports CRUD operations. The class or instance is the first argument to the `can_*` functions, and the second argument is the name of the property that should be checked. Type checking is done automatically to ensure that the functions are being used as expected. Please note that this is designed to only work with properties created with the `property` class from `builtins` module.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


def main():
    for kind in Test, TestG, TestS, TestGS, TestD, TestGD, TestSD, TestGSD:
        print(kind.__name__, 'Class')
        print('  can_get:', can_get(kind, 'data'))
        print('  can_set:', can_set(kind, 'data'))
        print('  can_del:', can_del(kind, 'data'))
        print()
        instance = kind('Hello, world!')
        print(kind.__name__, 'Instance')
        print('  can_get:', can_get(instance, 'data'))
        print('  can_set:', can_set(instance, 'data'))
        print('  can_del:', can_del(instance, 'data'))
        print()


def can_get(obj, key):
    return _get_property(obj, key).fget is not None


def can_set(obj, key):
    return _get_property(obj, key).fset is not None


def can_del(obj, key):
    return _get_property(obj, key).fdel is not None


def _get_property(obj, key):
    if not isinstance(obj, type):
        obj = type(obj)
    pro = vars(obj).get(key)
    if not isinstance(pro, property):
        raise TypeError('{.__name__}.{} is not a property'.format(obj, key))
    return pro


class Test:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__data = value

    def get_data(self):
        return self.__data

    def set_data(self, value):
        self.__data = value

    def del_data(self):
        del self.__data

    data = property()


class TestG(Test):

    data = property(fget=Test.get_data)


class TestS(Test):

    data = property(fset=Test.set_data)


class TestGS(Test):

    data = property(fget=Test.get_data, fset=Test.set_data)


class TestD(Test):

    data = property(fdel=Test.del_data)


class TestGD(Test):

    data = property(fget=Test.get_data, fdel=Test.del_data)


class TestSD(Test):

    data = property(fset=Test.set_data, fdel=Test.del_data)


class TestGSD(Test):

    data = property(fget=Test.get_data, fset=Test.set_data, fdel=Test.del_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This approach is already given in the question.  However, as Daenyth notes in his answer, it does not work in general.

Comment: That may be true, but depending on the code you are working with, it may work in specific -- which may be good enough for some.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  And this kind of solution is that I ended up doing in my code.

Comment: If you mention that this solution only applies to properties implemented using the the `property` decorator, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Done. It is unfortunate that there is not a more robust solution such as what Cat Plus Plus suggested. The only problem with that proposal is that it could modify underlying data unintentionally.

Comment: Yeah, but I guess a more robust solution would mean adding more method.  If we want that complexity, we have to add it ourselves.